# Java process physical memory increases continuously

Tags: memory, javafx, process

I've run into a situation where a simple canvas
Drawing app shows a gradual increase in physical 
Memory usage over time until it hits about 80% mark
And tries to maintain the process memory usage around
That number (that is the %MEM column when 'top' is run, 64bit Linux box). Of course by that point page swapping kicks in. I've tried to limit memory usage by using -Xmx10m -Xms10m and even -XX:+UseG1GC but nothing appears to make a difference. 
 Just a side note, I've even tried the StockLineChartApp example shipped with oracle jdk Javafx examples and it displays a physical memory usage increase as well. I'm using jdk1.8.0_102.

Any feedback regarding this issue would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
//

package test8;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.Animation;

public class Test8 extends Application {

   GraphicsContext gc;
     double x;
     double y;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      try {

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene s = new Scene(root, 600, 400, Color.BLACK);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,300);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("canvas test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

     gc.beginPath();

     x = 0.0;
     y = 0.0;

   EventHandler onFinished = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

           y = (y<canvas.getHeight()) ? (y + 10.0)   : 0.0;
           x = (x<canvas.getWidth())  ? (x + 5.0)    : 0.0;

           gc.lineTo(x,y);
           gc.stroke();
           if (x==0.0) gc.beginPath();

     }
      };


      final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
      timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
      timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
      timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(40), onFinished));
      timeline.play();

      } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Application start Exception");
      } finally {
      }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: This solved the issue for linux 64bit ....  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161997.    Basically use    -Dprism.order=sw    and it appears to contain continuously increasing system memory usage.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228866/optimizing-memory-leakage-in-javafx/40239829#40239829) (possible duplicate question)