# How to rotate shapes in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm looking for a simple way to rotate shapes in javafx. Right now I've  a scene with multiples shapes and I want to use a rotate button to select one of them and set a rotation of a specified angle, but I've no idea how to do that. Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [*Animation Basics*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm).

Comment: You can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734430/memory-leak-in-javafx-indefinite-timeline/44838669#44838669) to see an implementation of lines being rotated about one end like the hands of a clock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a simple request with many implementation alternatives, and some solutions are readily available
Code:

```
 Text text = new Text("This is a test");
 text.setX(10);
 text.setY(50);
 text.setFont(new Font(20));

 text.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(30, 50, 30));
```

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html)

[Some tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWGuu9AbMII)

Adding more is difficult given the lack of your code

Comment: My problem is how can i get the shape from the many ones shapes that are on the scene and then use the Rotate transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to get the button rotate with this code:

```
    @FXML
private void rotateButtonHandle(ActionEvent event) {
    //handle for rotate
    rotateButton.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent t) -> {
        System.out.println("X " + (t.getX()));
        System.out.println("\nY "+(t.getY()));
        Node shape = (Node) t.getSource();
        shape.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(20.0,t.getX(),t.getY()));
    });   

}
```

I dont know  how to get the shape in the scene.

Comment: Doesn't that just keep adding more and more transformations to the shape, so it would eventually get sluggish or run out of memory?