# Which are the things to consider for running javafx standalone application 24*7*365 days

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I am working on one project which is a standalone javafx application. It will run 24*7*365 days continuously.

So, i have a question in mind.

which things we need to consider for running this application smoothly and with high performance for 24*7*365?

Please guides me sir, regarding it.

Details for used things are as follows for Reference :-
Used java version :- 1.8.0_121
Available Ram :- 2GB
Allocated Memory for application :- -Xmx1524M
Hardware Configuration :-  Processor - Intel Atom CPUD425@ 1.80GHz x 2 
OS :- 32 Bit Fedora 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will probably state the obvious here, but `OutOfMemory` errors are the main thing you should worry about. A small glitch in your code/program could make your app die fast or run extremely slow under memory pressure.

I would say that you need to enable garbage collection logs and monitor those. Also is there a way for a `javafx` app to actually use another instance if the current one is facing issues? There are tools for that under different apps, but not sure about `javafx`... I mean can you *automatically* shut down (and collect heap data) the current running application and automatically start a new one (so that later you can analyze what actually happened)?  It might not be feasible, and if it's not, you should have enough *stress tests* before you actually lunch it into production.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should check first is whether your system suffers from the notorious memory problems that some Linux graphics drivers have. See for example my answer to this question here on SO:
[Javafx growing memory usage when drawing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395696/javafx-growing-memory-usage-when-drawing-image)

Comment: That particular issue is most probably solved in recent versions of Mesa and X.org: see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228866/optimizing-memory-leakage-in-javafx).